# Передача статического метода класса в multiprocessing.Process на Питоне 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6

Пытаюсь запустить статический метод класса через `multiprocessing.Process`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        pass

if __name__=="__main__":       
    proc = mp.Process(target=Test.method)
    proc.start()
```

Но сталкиваюсь с тем, что оно работает в питоне 3.6, но не работает в 3.4 (а для проекта требуется поддержка питона с 3.4). Полистав документацию, нашел, что [можно передавать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) только методы, определенные в top level'е модуля. Но тогда почему это работает в питоне 3.6? Посмотрев чейнджлоги, я не нашел изменения в этой механике. Соответственно встали вопросы:

1. Можно ли как то завернуть **произвольную** функцию или метод так, чтобы ее можно было передать в `Process`.

Для отдельно взятого метода можно сделать функцию-обертку на уровне модуля:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        pass

def method_wrapper(): # <======= This
    return Test.method()

if __name__=="__main__":       
    proc = mp.Process(target=method_wrapper)
    proc.start()
```

но это не подойдет, когда таких функций много. Можно ли сделать какую-то функцию, которая будет принимать нужный мне метод и возвращать что-то, что можно передать в `Process`

2. Соответствует ли поведение питона 3.6 тому, что в документации (или это баг/фича)? То есть могу ли я рассчитывать, что в будущем это поведение не изменится?

**P.S.**

Зачем мне это нужно? Глобально стоит задача ограничить время выполнения функций. То есть есть скрипт, который выполняет разные действия, и некоторые из них могут быть очень долгие, и нужно их прибить, если они выполняются дольше определенного времени, и сделать что-то с этим (или подождать и попробовать еще раз, или начать откат).  То есть что я пытаюсь сделать: запустить функцию/метод в отдельном процессе, подождать его в главном некоторое время и убить, если надо.

Потоки не подходят, я не могу их убить. Мне нужно гарантировать, что если время истекло, действие больше не выполняется, прежде чем работать дальше.

В общем если есть идеи, как это сделать по другому, буду рад идеям.

Comment: в 3.5 то, о чем речь в вопросе, работает

Comment: а что за долгие действия выполняются?

Comment: @rusnasonov не могу написать конкретно, так как это внутренние процессы коммерческого продукта, могу написать только, что есть некий сервер, который отправляет команды на клиенты, и если они не успели выполнить команду, то они должны остановить ее выполнение и попытаться вернуться в исходное состояние. На текущий момент эти команды являются функциями внутри питона, и изменить это нельзя. Будем думать над тем, чтобы вынести их в отдельные файлы и вызывать через subprocess, но пока есть что есть.

Comment: ваш пример работает на Питоне 2 и 3 на моей машине (Ubuntu). Укажите точную версию (к примеру, Python 3.4.4), какая OS?

Comment: windows Python 3.4.3 - не работает, версии питона выше - работают

Comment: @jfs поправка: выше 3.4 (ибо попробовал 3.4.4, и тоже не работает).

Comment: и на Python 3.4.3 у меня тоже работает (также как и на `envlist = py{27,33,34,35,36,37}, pypy{2,3}, jython2.7`). На моей машине ошибку удалось воспроизвести на Python 3.4{3,4,6} c `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`. Я сперва предположил, что ваша ошибка относится к pep 3154 и взаимодействию между pickle и `__qualname__`, но  `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Test.method, protocol=0..4))()` работает для всех версий протокола (на Python 3.6), а замена `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` не помогла на Python 3.4 c 'spawn' методом. Если не можете с Python 3.4 уйти, в качестве workaround...

Comment: ...можно пошевелить способ вызова: `def run_method(klass, methodname):
    getattr(klass, methodname)()`

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понимаю, у Вас trace при ошибке получается примерно таким (проверял на Python 3.4.4, Windows 7 64-bit):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiproc.py", line 17, in <module>
    proc.start()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Test.method at 0x0000000002A84730>
: attribute lookup method on __main__ failed

...
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 100, in spawn_main
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 81, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно
```

Обращает на себя внимание строка `Can't pickle <function Test.method at 0x0000000002A84730>`.

И действительно, до версии Python 3.5 `pickle` не поддерживал упаковку bound-методов. Начиная с версии 3.5 [поддерживает](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#pickle).

### Итого

1. Если есть необходимость использовать именно версию 3.4, то можно воспользоваться одним из советов: [Can't pickle  when using multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-multiprocessing-pool-map?rq=1) или [Pickling a staticmethod in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914261/pickling-a-staticmethod-in-python/1914798#1914798) (правда, нужно будет дополнить код обёртками).
2. Начиная с версии 3.5 всё работает и будет работать.

### Варианты доработок для Python 3.4

1. **Wrapper**

По совету @jfs в комментарии выше:

```
def wrapper(klass, method):
    getattr(klass, method)()


if __name__ == "__main__":   
    proc = mp.Process(target=wrapper, args=(Test, "method"))
    proc.start()
```

2. **Использовать метакласс**

По ответу с основного Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1914798/711380

```
class _PickleableStaticMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, cls=None):
        self.cls = cls
        self.fn = fn
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return _PickleableStaticMethod(self.fn, cls)
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.cls, self.fn.__name__)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.cls, name = state
        self.fn = getattr(self.cls, name).fn


class pickleable_staticmethods(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_cls = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        dct = new_cls.__dict__
        for name in dct.keys():
            value = new_cls.__dict__[name]
            if isinstance(value, staticmethod):
                setattr(
                        new_cls,
                        name,
                        _PickleableStaticMethod(value.__get__(None, new_cls),
                                               new_cls))
        return new_cls



class Test(metaclass=pickleable_staticmethods):
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        while True:
            print(time.ctime())
            time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":   
    proc = mp.Process(target=Test.method)
    proc.start()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Дополнил ответ примерами и номерами версий